# The algebra generated by $\pi_\alpha:[0,1]^S\to [0,1]$ is dense in $C([0,1]^S)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $S$ be a nonempty set, $X=[0,1]^S:\{f:S\to [0,1]:f\text{ is a function}\}$ and $A$ the algebra generated by the constant function $1$ and the coordinate applications
$$\pi_\alpha:X\to [0,1]\text{ given by } \pi_\alpha(f)=f(\alpha).$$
I need to prove that $A$ is dense on $C(X)$. It is clear that $A$ separates points, let $f\neq g\in X$, then there is an elemento $\alpha\in S$ such that $f(\alpha)\neq g(\alpha)$, that so $\pi_\alpha(f)\neq \pi_\alpha(g)$. But I still don't see how to prove that $X$ is closed, I saw out there that the Tychonoff's theorem is used, but I would like to know the details please.

Maybe I am misunderstanding things here. If anyone has any idea how to do it or what I'm wrong about, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: If $S$ is just a set what does continuity of $f:S \to [0,1]$ mean?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy You are very right, sorry, I already edited the question.

Comment: What is the topology on $X$ and what do you mean by saying that $X is closed? Closed in what?

Comment: Are you using the product topology?

Comment: That's what I'm not sure about, I think with the product topology, I don't know. It is just what does not allow me to understand everything well. What I clearly want to do is apply the Stone Weierstrass theorem, but that little obstacle does not allow me.

Comment: If you want a chance of applying Tychonoff you would need the product topology. But you still need a (non zero) constant.